# Flask return Pandas DataFrame to AJAX - Errno 10054

Tags: python, ajax, pandas, flask, dataframe

I am trying to create a simple Web Application that will return historical stock data after the user has defined a stock symbol in a form I've created.  My approach has been to supply a form where the user can specify the stock symbol and send that text back to the server using AJAX.  Once the text is received on the server side I am using Pandas functionality to retrieve historical stock data from Yahoo Finance.

I am able to receive the text on the server, retrieve the historical stock data, but when I attempt to send that back to my AJAX function I receive the following error message:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54959)
----------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2015 06:12:07] "POST /get_stock_data HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 657, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 716, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have tried many different approaches for sending the data back, but I always receive an error.  From what I can tell the issue is caused when using the DataReader functionality to retrieve the stock data.  If I exclude that I can retrieve and send anything back and forth.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script type=text/javascript>$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};</script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">                   

    </head>


    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="Symbol" name="Symbol" id="symbol">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            <div id="container"></div>

            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
                        $.ajax( {
                            type: 'post',
                            url: '/get_stock_data',
                            data: $('form').serialize(),
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function result) {
                                console.log("success")                          
                            },

                            error: function() {
                                console.log("failure has occured")
                            }
                        })
                    });
                });

            </script>   
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

import pandas.io.data as web

app = Flask(__name__)

def getStockData(symbol):
    stock = web.DataReader(symbol, 'yahoo')
    return stock

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

@app.route('/get_stock_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_symbol():
    sym = request.form['Symbol']

    stock = getStockData(sym)

    return jsonify(result=stock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Can anyone explain what this error means and how I can resolve it?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: start with fixing the function definition: you have 'sybmol' instead of 'symbol' as your input argument. I'm guessing flask is failing on this and since it's an ajax call it might not show where (unless it does and you didn't include the full error msg).

Comment: I fixed my input argument (accidental typo), but still run into the same issues.  I've updated my post to include the entire error message on the python side.  My browser console never returns anything.